# Custom Toggle Button using c# code in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to create custom toggle button using C# code. Please refer below snap, it should act like a toggle button.

[image]

Comment: First link in google: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/form_elements/togglebutton/

Comment: are you using Xaml? have you tried triggers?

Comment: this is only android i need to use this toggle button in ios , android , windows app using xamarin.forms by using c# code

Comment: i am using C# Code design

Comment: Did you find any difficulty in implementation, you unaccepted ?

Comment: now i don't have any difficulty.  https://github.com/sam-ss/Custom-Segmented-Control-Xamarin-Forms

Comment: That has the similar implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the plugin, you need to perform custom rendering.
 https://github.com/chrispellett/Xamarin-Forms-SegmentedControl

The above github repository has the source code for custom rendering for segmented button in `andorid` and `ios` only not for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SegmentedButtonGroup in FreshEssentials. It looks like that is what you need.

http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/freshessentials-for-xamarin-forms-the-must-have-nuget-for-forms/

Comment: need to create custom segmented button without using plugin